# Rendering autocomplete suggestions in a pre-defined html block using jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, customization, jquery-autocomplete

I have a predefined HTML code say,

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
   <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

and I have a input box. I have a remote source which can return me the results in jsonp format. I want to utilize jquery's autocomplete feature, but instead of the results being shown in a dropdown newly created div, I want to populate them in my existing HTML shown above.

I tried searching a lot for it, but I don't seem to find a way to do that. I'm fairly new to jquery, so pardon me if I'm missing something too obvious.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery UI autocomplete has inbuilt functionality to [customize the display](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) of the results. [**This demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDg/1/) shows how it can be achieved which overrides the `_renderItem` method of the "autocomplete" data attribute inside the jQuery UI autocomplete code.

HTML

```
<label for="tags">Tags: </label><input id="tags" />
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    search: function(event, ui) {
       // clear the existing result set
       $('#wrapper').empty();
    },
})
.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $('<div class="element"></div>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<a href="#">' + item.label+ '</a>')
        .appendTo($('#wrapper'));
    };
```

CSS& (to hide the normal container)

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    display:none !important;
}
```

You can customize each *item* by changing the markup inside the `.append()` method in the `.data('autocomplete')` function and you may want to look at the other autocomplete *Events* if you want to manipulate the `<div id="wrapper">` search results further, for example clearing the list if the `<input>` acquires focus.

Comment: But I don't understand the purpose of ".data('item.autocomplete', item)" Why is that necessary?

Comment: If you look for `_renderItem` in the [jQuery UI v1.8.14 code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js), you can see the default jQuery UI function that the code in my answer is overriding to append the results to your `<div>` instead of the normal autocomplete `<ul>`

Comment: Suggestion should be hide when I click anywhere except in that div region. Currently suggestion is hiding only one event which is search for new keyword. Do you know how to hide suggestion if someone click outside that div?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari you could attach a function to the `blur` event on the `<input>` for example `$('#tags').blur(function() { $('#wrapper').empty(); });` or attach a `click` event handler to the the `window` object to hide the suggestions.

Comment: @andyb, this will give you an issue when selecting items. It just doesn't work because Autocomplete expects the elements to be <li><a>..</a></li>: http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDg/92/

Answer (score 0):

When you say remote source do you mean a database or are you using an iframe?

If its a database then you are retrieving from some back end code.  Here is an example ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'path/to/server/code',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
      //where you would work with the object
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    jsonpCallback: function() {
        //your callback funciton
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a website which based on the query parameters, returns me the jsonp results

Comment: are you using jquery ui autocomplete?  Also i don't believe the data has to be jsonp, it can just be json that might be causing an error...just a thought

Comment: Andre, what I am trying to accomplish is to use autocomplete of a certain text input to populate a pre-defined html instead of a new dropdown style div suggesting me results. Am I making myself more explainable?